# Telling IE not to ask for Saving a document and always opening a new tab for it

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I show some PDF icons on my page and when user clicks on them it will open the PDF in a new tab when I use Chrome.

```
                    <a href="@licImage.ImageUrl" target="_blank">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/genericPDFicon.png" class="pdfIcon thumbnail"/>
                    </a>
```

But if user is using IE they will see this instead of new tab:

[image]

How can I tell IE not to do that and just open the doc in new tab just like any other normal browser!?

Comment: IE is not a normal browser

Comment: Is your IE capable of viewing PDFs? I seem to recall IE not having that ability by default, and requiring a plugin like Adobe Reader or something similar. If it can't open a PDF, its only choice is to save it.

Comment: @JoeEnos oh I see, good call. will check on that.